# How to uncheck the checkcolumn of perticular row in Ext grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a grid which has a column of checkboxes. I have used xtype ***checkcolumn***

for this. follow fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ano

Now I want to uncheck checkbox at perticular(in this case 2nd) row on click of given button. I tried getting them using xtypes but no luck.

finally I found a workaround.

```
store.getAt(1).data.active = false;
grid.getView().refresh();
```

It works but not sure if its the correct way to do so.
I will be glad for any suggestions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One way as per your code.

You can use this methods of grid store **[`store.each()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each)**,  **[`store.clearFilter()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter)** and **[`store.filter('active',true)`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter)**.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ant)**, you can check here `uncheck` checked columns using `record.set('active',false)`.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'active'],
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-111-1224',
        active: false
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1234',
        active: true
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1244',
        active: false
    }, {
        name: 'Marge',
        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1254',
        active: false
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    itemId: 'test',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: store,
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Un check',
        handler: function () {
            var store = this.up('grid').getStore();
            store.clearFilter();
            store.filter('active', true);
            store.each(function (rec) {
                rec.set('active', false);
            });
            store.clearFilter();
        }
    }],
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        text: 'Active',
        dataIndex: 'active'
    }]
});
```

> Another way as per your code.

You can use [`selModel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-selModel)  and [`selType`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-selType) configs for [`grid`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel).

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26ea)**, I have created a demo using `selType` and `selModel` config. it will help you or guide you more about `grid` checkbox selection.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Simpsons',
        store: store,
        id: 'testGrid',
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Phone',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        selModel: {
            checkOnly: false,
            //injectCheckbox: 'last',
            mode: 'SIMPLE'
        },
        selType: 'checkboxmodel',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Select All',
            handler: function () {
                Ext.getCmp('testGrid').getSelectionModel().selectAll();
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Deselect All',
            handler: function () {
                Ext.getCmp('testGrid').getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
            }
        }]
    });
```

Comment: I was looking for the first solution. Thanks @Njdhv.